# IndexError from calling an Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack-overflow

I'm working on an infix to prefix program utilizing a stack class. However, the push() method is raising an IndexError whenever I call an integer, even though I have an Exception Handler and I'm referencing the integer itself, not a list.

stack.py:

```
class stack():
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n = n
        self.top = -1
        self.stack = [""] * n

    #...

    def push(self,c):
        try:
            print(self.top)
            self.top += 1
            self.stack[self.top] = c
        except IndexError:
            print("Stack is full.")
```

pip.py:

```
def toPrefix(input):
    instack = stack(15)
    prefix = ""

    for i in range(0,len(input)):
        for c in range(0,len(input[i])):
            if(input[i][c].isalpha()):
                instack.push(input[i][c])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 247, in run_nodebug
  File "P:\Scripts\Python\ascl-pip.py", line 42, in <module>
    toPrefix(infix)
  File "P:\Scripts\Python\ascl-pip.py", line 37, in toPrefix
    instack.push(input[i][c])
  File "P:\Scripts\Python\stack.py", line 36, in push
    print(self.top)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Please always include the full traceback of the error message you get.

Comment: And you don't need to implement a stack.  Standard Python lists have `append()` and `pop()` methods.

Comment: @SvenMarnach it's for a class that requires I write my own stack class.

Comment: What is your input to `toPrefix`

Comment: input is a list of three strings. "abcde", "abcde", and "abcdef", so there _should_ be an IndexError, but it's not being caught by the Exception Handler, and the IndexError isn't coming from the input or stack variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traceback is inconsistent.  It claims the line

```
print(self.top)
```

is the reason for the `IndexError`, but `print()` will never raise such an error.

The only way this can happen is that you are using an old version of your module that is still loaded in an interpreter instance.  Restart your interpreter.

If you really need to implement your own stack class, you could go with something stupid like this:

```
class Stack(list):
    push = list.append
```

This stack will have an unlimited size.

Comment: `push = list.append` now that's just trying to beat the system :) I don't think whoever is marking the assignment would be too impressed by that

Comment: @KshitijMehta: My attitude is that ridiculous assignments should get ridiculous solutions.  If you are supposed to implement a stack in C, that's fine.  A stack in Python will inevitably be based on a list, though, so you are supposed to write a stack implementation on top of a stack implementation.  My suggested implementation merely emphasizes this point.